# ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB Image Formats

Tags: android, renderscript

What YUV ImageFormats (e.g. `ImageFormat.NV21`, `ImageFormat.YV12`, and `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`) are supported by `ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB` (SIYTB)?

What Element should be used for `SIYTB.create()`?
The SIYTB overview says "The output is RGBA; the alpha channel will be set to 255", but the documentation for create() says "Supported elements types are `U8_4`". Should the `Element` type for create() actually be `Element.RGBA_8888`?

What `Element` type should be used to construct the `Type.Builder` used to build the `Type` for the input `Allocation`?
The SIYTB documentation says "The input allocation should be supplied in a supported YUV format as a YUV element Allocation." Does this imply to use `Element.YUV` to construct the `Type.Builder`?

Should `Type.Builder.setY()` be used in conjunction with `Type.Builder.setX()` when creating an input `Allocation` for `SIYTB`?
If `Type.Builder.setY()` should be used...
* Should it be used for NV21, YV21, and YUV_420_888?
* Should `Type.Builder.setX()` typically be set to the image width and `Type.Builder.setY()` typically be set to the image height?

Should `Type.Builder.setYuvFormat()` be used when creating an input Allocation for `SIYTB`?
If `Type.Builder.setYuvFormat()` should be used...
* Should it be used for NV21, YV21, and YUV_420_888?
* Does it help `SIYTB` know how to parse a YUV Image byte array?

What YUV image byte array layout is required for `SIYTB` input via `Allocator.copyFrom()`?
I am guessing the byte array must be packed with no pixel strides or row strides. But the byte array packing of NV21, YV12, and YUV_420_888 is different, e.g. order and size of UV planes. So how is `SIYTB` to know the layout of the input byte array? I am guessing it is via `Type.Builder.setYuvFormat()`.

Is there an easy way to convert an Android Image to a byte array? For example something similar to `Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer()`?  (wink, nudge, Android Team)

Thanks for reading this...

Comment: There are many questions (about 8) here. Could you write a single, focused question? That is more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, They are all questions about how to use ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB. I am hoping Eddy Talvala or R. Jason Sams might answer them in one spot. I will create three separate questions if needed, e.g. How to use SIYTB with NV21, ibid NV12, ibid YUV_420_888. These questions have been asked by others but SIYTB seems to be a moving target and the spartan documentation has changed with addition of new properties and methods, e.g. Element.YUV(), setYuvFormat()